# returning html from an http get request using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm a bit of a newbie, I have been trolling through many stackoverflow pages to find the answers I'm looking for but had no success.

what i am trying to do is:

have just a text box & a button on a page

a word is entered, the button is pressed

the search result is displayed on the page in a fancy way

easy right?

I am have a html form submit section:

```
<form id="searchHashtag" action="http://localhost:5000/search" method="get">
<label for="hashtag">Search for a hashtag:</label> 
<input type="text" name="hashtag" />
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
```

then a javascript function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >

    <!--  submit action -->
    var resp;                   
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#searchHashtag").submit( function(event)
        {   
            console.log("event");
        event.preventDefault();

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).attr('action'),
                type :$(this).attr('method'),
                        data :$(this).serialize(),

            success :function(response){
                 $("#contactResponse").show();
                         resp = response;    
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
               console.log("xhr " + xhr.status);
               console.log("status " + status);
               console.log("error " + errorThrown);
            }
             });
                 return false;
          });
        });     

        </script>
```

and my CSS has:

```
#contactResponse {
    height: 600px;
    width: 750px;
    display: none;
}
```

the response Html field:

```
<div class="contentMain">
    <h1>Search results</h1>

        <div id="contactResponse">
                   **Display search results(resp) in a fancy way**   
            </div>

    </div>
```

Now here is the problem, on button press the search goes out:

```
`http://localhost:5000/search?hashtag=**requestedWord**`
```

the search head receives the request no problems
its return is currently hard coded to:

```
<html>OK</html>
```

the http response comes back 200 and immediately redirects to a page:

```
http://localhost:5000/search?hashtag=**requestedWord**
```

and on the page it displays "OK".
I have tried changing the return of the search head to a string:

```
"OK"
```

even to json

```
({'id:'OK'})
```

but everything just redirects to a page displaying "OK"

I thought `success :function(response){` was supposed to capture the response then allow me to use it.

what am I doing wrong?
Please help I don't have enough hair left to be tearing it out like this......

thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: I would have thought you went into an endless loop by inserting `<html>OK</html>`

Comment: Oh, also, make sure your `submit` handler is actually firing -- it's possible that it's not getting attached for some reason. Make your `submit` listener produce debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works ok for me. You are correctly calling preventDefault on your submit event. You need to ensure however that your html markup is correct. i.e. is there a closing form tag?

If your form html is invalid, jQuery won't be able to find your form (or attach to the submit event at least), but the browser will still work and post the form, therefore reloading your page.

Comment: thanks for your reply I had missed the closing tag, I have added it & it still doesn't work. I changed the code above to match current state.

Comment: All looks good to me. Maybe try adding a console.log call in your success handler to ensure it's being called. The 'redirect' you mention though does sound like the standard form submission is happening, which might suggest an error somewhere else in your html or javascript. Are there any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: to be on the safe side i ran the file through our friends at w3schools [link](http://validator.w3.org/check) validated fine

Comment: If the form is still submitting then there must be an issue with the javascript somewhere. Have a look at this very most basic case. http://jsfiddle.net/hDR8b/ You'll see that the form doesn't submit, which is what you want. You need to look at the rest of your code, maybe try creating a new html page with only the relevant code on it and see if it works.

Comment: I added the console.log (see above) and the only error being thrown is a syntax error on the line `data :$(this).serialize(),` the error is `missing : after property id.` I've checked several pages & I'm stumped where the colon is suppoed to go

Comment: Is it complaining about the space before the colon? I don't get that syntax error though, even with the space. Which browser are you using?